# WebHistoryItem: URL vs Original URL

Tags: android, android-webview

In [`WebHistoryItem`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebHistoryItem.html#getUrl())'s documentation says:

[**URL**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebHistoryItem.html#getUrl())

> Return the url of this history item. The url is the base url of this history item. See getTargetUrl() for the url that is the actual target of this history item.

[**Original URL**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebHistoryItem.html#getOriginalUrl())

> Return the original url of this history item. This was the requested url, the final url may be different as there might have been redirects while loading the site.

It makes me confused enough. What I want to know is, what are differences between them? Can you give me some examples?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, after I did some research I found differences between them. **Original URL** is a URL before redirected. Suppose that you opening a shorten link like this `https://bit•ly/sG98iK`, then you will be redirected to a web page with the following URL `https://example.com/android/tutorial/webview.html`. We call `https://bit•ly/sG98iK` as **original URL**, and `https://example.com/android/tutorial/webview.html` as **URL**, i.e. the URL after redirected.

Notice that original URL is *nullable*.

Answer (score 0):

When you load a website using an URL, the website may redirect to another website with a different URL.

Assume the scenario is like this: Website 1 (URL1) -> Website2 (URL2) -> Website3 (URL3)

then, getUrl will give you URL3. Meanwhile getOriginalURL will return URL1